# SharePoint 2010 - Web Analytics - Analyze Ribbon - missing feature

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-analytics

In SharePoint 2010 web analytics, I click on the report, then click on Analyze, google tells me I should now see an option to "Schedule Alerts or Reports" and to set the Site Scope.

I dont see these options, are they configured somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Is the ribbon missing completely, or are the options missing from the ribbon? It should look like this:
[image]